# adding stripe server code to Backendless Cloud

Tags: android, stripe-payments, backendless

I am trying to integrate stripe into my android application with the server code set up in Backendless as a Custom API Service. After charging the card, with a successful call back method, I am not able to see that in my payments list on my stripe dashboard. Not sure where the problem is. Any suggestions will be appreciated.Below is what I have so far:
ChargeItem://Charge Class

```
package com.mbaas.service;

public class ChargeItem {
   public String token;
   public int price;
   public String description;
 }
```

ChargeService //Backendless Service

```
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.StripeException;
import com.stripe.model.Charge;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ChargeService implements IBackendlessService
{
    public boolean makeCharge(ChargeItem charges){
    Stripe.apiKey = "my stripe secret key";

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    String token = charges.token;
    double price = charges.price;
    String desc = charges.description;
    String userId = charges.userId;
    String orderId = charges.orderId;

    // Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
    try {
      Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      chargeParams.put("orderId",orderId);
      chargeParams.put("userId",userId);
      chargeParams.put("amount", price); // Amount in cents
      chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
      chargeParams.put("source", token);
      chargeParams.put("description", desc);
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
    } 
    catch (StripeException e) {
      // The card has been declined
        return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
}
```

//My stripe token call back method

```
private  void convertCardToToken(Card card, final Orders order){
                 Stripe stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(),              CustomApplication.PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
    stripe.createToken(
            card,
            new TokenCallback() {
                public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                    // Send token to your server
                    ChargeItem chargeItem = new ChargeItem();
                    chargeItem.setToken(token.getId());
                    chargeItem.setOrderId(order.getObjectId());
                    chargeItem.setPrice(order.getOrder_price());
                    chargeItem.setUserName(order.getOwnerId());
                    chargeItem.setDescription("Delivery Fee");
                    ChargeService.initApplication();
                    ChargeService chargeService =     ChargeService.getInstance();
                    chargeService.makeChargeAsync(chargeItem, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse(Boolean response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                   "Payment Successful",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                           ).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fault.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();


                        }
                    });
                }
                public void onError(Exception error) {
                    // Show localized error message
                    Toast.makeText(CheckoutActivity.this,
                            error.getLocalizedMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Backendless so I cannot provide much help here, but there a few issues with your code:

- `price` is a `double`. To avoid rounding errors, all amounts in Stripe's API are in cents (or more generally, in the smallest unit for the currency you're using), so `price` should be an `int`.
- `userId` and `orderId` are not valid parameters when [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge). You likely want to pass these variables as [metadata values](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#storing-information-in-metadata).

To help you debug further, you should also check your logs in your Stripe account's dashboard at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs?method=not_get. You should see requests to `POST /v1/tokens` (sent by your Android app) and requests to `POST /v1/charges` (sent by Backendless).

Comment: Hi @Ywain , thank you for the reply. I realised the problem was with the additional parameters I added after checking my logs. Implementing stripe for the first time and didn't know i could see my logs from the dashboard as well. That helped a lot

Comment: @GadoseyP. Glad I could help! :)